# Añadiendo "re" antes los verbos

Tags: gramática

En inglés se usa el prefijo *re-* antes un verbo para denotar hacer el verbo otra vez más.(assign --> reassign, randomize --> rerandomize). ¿Puede añadir este prefijo antes los verbos? (asignar -> reasignar, aleatorizar -> realeatorizar)

---

In English *re-* is usually added to verbs. Are the same done to Spanish verbs?

Comment: You can also add 're' to the beginning of adjectives to mean 'very'. eg. rebien, redifícil, etc. Pretty sure this is highly colloquial though and only used in some latin american countries.

Comment: @Kage reemphasis  in **highly**

Answer (score 4):

El prefijo **re-** tiene [varios significados](http://dle.rae.es/re) en español; entre ellos, el de repetición, como en inglés.

Comment: Importante en esta respuesta es que el significado no es siempre el mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Sí y tiene básicamente el mismo significado. *re-* es un prefijo productivo.

Comment: Habría que considerar si es necesario recontestar esta pregunta

Comment: Y reconsiderar...

Comment: @Dr.belisarius - Pero parece que Carlos aportó su respuesta primero, ¿no?